# How to compare two arraylist?

Tags: java, android

I have two `ArrayList`. Each is of size 100000. I want to compare them and count matched elements.

Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mArryLst2.size(); i++) {
   if (ArryLst1.contains(mArryLst2.get(i))) {
       matchedPixels++;         
   }
}
```

Here comparison process is taking lot of time.

How to solve and optimize this problem.

Comment: To easily compare objects, you should use a Set/HashSet instead of an List/ArrayList.

Comment: What are the types of the array list elements?

Comment: Also, are elements unique? Looks like it. If so, you should use a `HashSet`, not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: If an element E is contained once in array1 and twice in array2, does it count as one or two matches? What if is contained twice in both arrays?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should use `CollectionUtils.retainAll` : Returns a collection containing all the elements in collection1 that are also in collection2.

```
ArrayList commonList = CollectionUtils.retainAll(list1,list2);
```

Comment: Do they need to access the common elements or just the count of them?

Comment: plz mention the link for the jar file

Comment: you can find it in commons-collections.jar, there are lot of sites to download it.

Comment: Download commons-collections.jar from here  =>  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonscollectionsjar.htm

Answer (score 5):

You should transform you first list into a HashSet. HashSet lookups are O(1), and List lookups are O(n). This makes the whole algorithm O(n) rather than O(n^2)

```
Set<Foo> set1 = new HashSet<Foo>(list1);
for (Foo foo : list2) {
    if (set1.contains(foo)) {
        matchedPixels++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what? The OP wants to check if the list contains some element. If it contains it, the set will contain it. If it doesn't contain it, the set won't contain it.

Comment: The results of the ops method might differ from the results if he uses HashSets thats the point.

Comment: No, it can't be different. Re-read my comment. The OP doesn't count the number of times an element is contained in the list. It checks if it's in the list or not. How could it be in the list and not be in the set containing the same elements as the list (only one time rather than several)?

Comment: Many people suggested this solution but +1 for giving an explanation why it will be faster.

Comment: @JB Nizet: the op traverses ArrayList mArryLst2. mArryLst2 may contain duplicates .. ! if mArryLst2 contains the elements "1", "1" and mArryLst2 "1" the result will be 2. You will not have this result with HashSets.

Comment: That's why my answer tells the OP to transform the **first** list into a HashSet. And not the second one.

Answer (score 2):

you should look at this link [How to compare two Arraylist values in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163293/how-to-compare-two-arraylist-values-in-java). make a copy of one of the list and then call remove all for the list against the other list

```
List result = new ArrayList(mArryLst2);
result.removeAll(ArryLst1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to speed this up (especially for large arrays) and simplify the code;

```
    // Quick Check to see if the two arrayLists have the same number of elements
    if (array1.size() != array2.size())
        return false;

    // Optionally Sort the arrays - avoid returning false if the elements are the same but 
    // have been stored out of sequence
    Collections.sort(array1);
    Collections.sort(array2);

    if (array1.hashCode() == array2.hashCode()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to imply that two ArrayLists array1 and array2 contain the same elements if they have the same hash code, then you are **wrong**!

Comment: Also sorting would only help if there is a total order on the elements (which the OP didn't mention), in which case you could use a binary search to locate the elements of one ArrayList in the other one. For this you had only to sort one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ArrayList Listname = ListUtils.retainAll(list1,list2);
```

Comment: You should mention that `ListUtils` is not Android native class. Its from apache commons-collections.

Answer (score 0):

best option is to put all the elements of your 1st ArrayList into a Set(it allows only unique elements).

Now, from ur 2nd ArrayList, add each element to your Set, if the element already exists in your set, then it will return false.

if you have 2 arrayLists ArrayList1 and ArrayList2 and you want all the matches in another ArrayList Diff

```
HashSet hs = new HashSet();

for(int i : ArrayList1) hs.add(i);

for(int i : ArrayList2)  
 {

if(!hs.add(i))
  Diff.add(i);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be faster i think

```
    Set set = new HashSet();
    set.addAll(ArryLst1);

    for (int i = 0; i <mArryLst2.size(); i++)
    {
       if (set .contains(mArryLst2.get(i))) 
       {
             matchedPixels++;        
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is Override equals method and check if each object in your array list is equal or not.

```
    public class CustomClass {
        String x;
        String a;
        String b;
        String c;
        long l;
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return (this.blindlyEquals(obj) && ((CustomClass) obj).blindlyEquals(this));
        }
        protected boolean blindlyEquals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof CustomClass))
                return false;
            CustomClass p = (CustomClass)o;
            return (p.x == this.x && p.a == this.a && p.b == this.b && p.c == this.c && p.l == this.l);
        }

    }


    public class MainClass {

        ArrayList<CustomClass> member = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
        ArrayList<CustomClass> server;
        /**
         * @param args
         */

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
            mainClass.server = mainClass.getServerList();
            mainClass.member = mainClass.getLocalList();


            if(mainClass.member.equals(mainClass.server)){
                System.out.println("true");
//do the needfull, run a for loop to check which object is  not equal
            }else{
                System.out.println("false");
//do the needfull, run a for loop to check which object is  not equal
            }

        }
        public ArrayList<CustomClass> getServerList(){
            ArrayList<CustomClass> server = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
            CustomClass obj = new CustomClass();
            CustomClass obj2 = new CustomClass();
            obj.a = "ali";
            obj.b = "ball";
            obj.c = "cat";
            obj.x = "xerox";
            obj.l = 10;

            obj2.a = "ali";
            obj2.b = "ball";
            obj2.c = "cat";
            obj2.x = "xerox";
            obj2.l = 10;

            server.add(obj);
            server.add(obj2);
            return server;
        }

        public ArrayList<CustomClass> getLocalList(){
            ArrayList<CustomClass> memberOne = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
            CustomClass obj = new CustomClass();
            CustomClass obj2 = new CustomClass();
            obj.a = "ali";
            obj.b = "ball";
            obj.c = "cat";
            obj.x = "xerox";
            obj.l = 10;

            obj2.a = "ali";
            obj2.b = "ball";
            obj2.c = "cat";
            obj2.x = "xerox";
            obj2.l = 10;

            memberOne.add(obj);
            memberOne.add(obj2);
            return memberOne;
        }
    }
```