# Comparing two ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, comparison, sorting, similarity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare two arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589351/how-to-compare-two-arraylist)

I have two String ArrayLists of different sizes. I need to write a method that returns true iff  List A (larger list) contains every value of List B (smaller list). How would I go about writing such a method?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  As in, are you required to author your own solution instead of using something from the API?

Comment: Two for loops iterating through each list. However every time I get a match it returns true (even if i haven't gotten through the entire list. I have also tried setting check booleans for each element, but I couldn't figure out how to check the checks!

Comment: This is for my own program. Not homework

Comment: I got it! listB.containsAll(listA) was all it took!

Comment: Your line is the opposite to what you asked in your question.  listB.containsAll(listA) is saying does listB contain every value of listA which will be false if listB is smaller.

Comment: @Glitch What if `List a = [1,1]` and `List b = [1]`?

Comment: @cheeken you are right, it will be true if the larger list is made up of duplicates of the smaller list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`List.containsAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

Sometimes a peek at the documentation is all it takes (even for homework ;]).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should be using sets instead of lists.  Performing this operation on a list will be `O(N^2)`, whereas it will be `O(N)` or `O(NlogN)` for a HashSet or TreeSet respectively.

But if performance is not a major concern (i.e. the lists are relatively small, or you are doing the operation infrequently) then just use the `containsAll` method on the appropriate list object.

Answer (score 0):

```
            public boolean containsAll(List<String> listA, List<String> listB) {
                Set<String> listAAsSet = new HashSet<String>(listA);

                for (String string : listB) {

                    if(listAAsSet.contains(string)==false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
```

alternatively you can use `List.containsAll()` :)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient way, but what you can do is loop through the large list, and for every element in the large list, loop through the small list. Break out of the small list early if you find it, if it didn't find it, return false.

```
bool found = false;

for (string a : listA)
{
   found = false;
   for (string b : listB)
   {
      if (b.equals(a))
      {
         found = true;
         break;
      }
   }

   if (!found)
      return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: There is no more efficient way ... unless you convert to a different data structure.