# Compare two different ArrayLists for matching element

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, compare

I have two array list I want to compare the requested element against the allowed element.

If requested element is present in the allowed elements it should print

```
"Allowed elements  <element1>, <element2>, <element3>"
```

and

If requested element is not present in the allowed elements it should print

```
"Not allowed <element1>, <element2>, <element3>"
```

My Code

```
public class testList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> Alist = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> Blist = new ArrayList<String>();

        // allowed elements
        Alist.add("NAME");
        Alist.add("SUBJECT");
        Alist.add("MARKS");

        // requested elements
        Blist.add("NAME");
        Blist.add("AGE");
        Blist.add("DOB");
        Blist.add("SUBJECT");
        Blist.add("MARKS");
        Blist.add("AVERAGE");
        Blist.add("MOBILE");
        Blist.add("EMAIL");

    }
}
```

and the result should be:

If EMAIL and MOBILE are requested which is not in allowed elements should print "**Not allowed EMAIL and MOBILE**"

If NAME, SUBJECT and MARKS are requested which are allowed elements should print "**Allowed NAME, SUBJECT and MARKS**"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simpler way to compare 2 arraylist in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155283/simpler-way-to-compare-2-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: so in the above case when Blist contains the above 8 elements, what should be printed?

Comment: what you have tried??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple code for your problem, try this and tell me if any:

```
StringBuilder allowBuilder = new StringBuilder("Allowed ");
StringBuilder notAllowBuilder = new StringBuilder("Not allowed ");

List<String> allowList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> notAllowList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String blistItem : Blist) {
    if (Alist.contains(blistItem)) {
        allowList.add(blistItem);
    } else {
        notAllowList.add(blistItem);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < allowList.size(); i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        allowBuilder.append(allowList.get(i));
    } else {
        if (i + 1 < allowList.size()) {
            allowBuilder.append(", ").append(allowList.get(i));
        } else {
            allowBuilder.append(" and ").append(allowList.get(i));
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < notAllowList.size(); i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        notAllowBuilder.append(notAllowList.get(i));
    } else {
        if (i + 1 < notAllowList.size()) {
            notAllowBuilder.append(", ").append(notAllowList.get(i));
        } else {
            notAllowBuilder.append(" and ").append(notAllowList.get(i));
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(notAllowBuilder.toString());
System.out.println(allowBuilder.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
Not allowed AGE, DOB, AVERAGE, MOBILE and EMAIL
Allowed NAME, SUBJECT and MARKS
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. It should either print allowed fields if matches or not allowed fields if no matches.. In the above case if it matches it prints "Not allowed"
"Allowed NAME, SUBJECT and MARKS"

Comment: you can check size of 2 list allowed and notAllowed before print output.

Comment: codeaholic: Thanks for the snippet. I was helpful. You rock :)

Comment: nice, im happy because it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    List<String> newBlist = new ArrayList<String>(Blist);

    newBlist.removeAll(Alist);

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();        
    List<String> responseList;
    if (newBlist.isEmpty()) {
        response.append("Allowed ");
        responseList = Blist;
    } else {
        response.append("Not Allowed ");
        responseList = newBlist;
    }

    for (String str : responseList) {
        response.append(str).append(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(response.toString());
```