# How can i to make anagram program using two character Arraylists?

Tags: java, arraylist, anagram

this is the Code i have, what should i do ?

It's not even a String. it use Arraylist.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ArrayCheck {
public boolean isAnagram(ArrayList<Character> arr1, ArrayList<Character> arr2) {
   }

}
```

Comment: Do your homework by yourself!

Comment: how do you intend to check if a newly composed string is a valid word? where is your dictionary?

Comment: Please attempt something. When you get stuck and you don't understand why, you can come back here and ask.

Comment: How about you **make** two strings out of the character lists?

Comment: Hint: you don't actually need strings for the solution.

Comment: @Harmlezz in this case I think an anagram is literally just checking if the length is the same, and characters too but in whatever (random) order. I suspect it's a homework assignment where the exercise provides the method signature

Comment: Actually your question is somehow reduced to [How to compare two ArrayLists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155283/simple-way-to-compare-2-arraylists).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got the impression that you are kind of lost. Hence to get you started here how you may approach your task:

- define a `dictionary` containing all words you will accept.
- make sure the newly created string (in your case I guess `arr2`) is composed of the same characters as the original word (in your case I guess `arr1`)
- if your validation succeeds, lookup the newly created string in your `dictionary` and if it exists, it is an anagram. Otherwise it is not.

Comment: can you please make some code that i can understand with ?