# How to optimize comparison of unsorted ArrayLists which contain unsorted ArrayLists

Tags: java, sorting, optimization, comparison

I have two ArrayLists of objects where both are unsorted, but could/should have the same values, again, just unsorted.
There are no unique identifiers within these ArrayLists.
Each ArrayList contains another ArrayList which is the meat of what I need to compare, but this ArrayList is again, unsorted.

To compare the ArrayLists I am having to use a String for its class name (can be repeat), a String for its name(can be repeat), and the ArrayList of actions contained within.

Currently I am creating my comparitors, sorting the original ArrayLists, then sorting the internal ArrayLists, and then looping through the list comparing values.

```
    ArrayList<PersistablePermission> oldPermissions = 
            new ArrayList<PersistablePermission>( oldRole.getPermissions() );

    ArrayList<PersistablePermission> newPermissions = 
            new ArrayList<PersistablePermission>( newRole.getPermissions() );

    if( oldPermissions.size() != newPermissions.size() ) {
        return true;
    }

    Comparator<PersistablePermission> comparePermissions = new 
    Comparator<PersistablePermission>() {
        public int compare( PersistablePermission p1, PersistablePermission p2 ) {
            return p1.compareTo( p2 );
        }
    };
    Comparator<PersistablePermission> comparePermissions = new Comparator<PersistablePermission>() {
        public int compare( PersistablePermission p1, PersistablePermission p2 ) {
            return p1.compareTo( p2 );
        }
    };

    Comparator<String> compareActions = new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.compareTo( s2 );

        }
    };
    oldPermissions.sort( comparePermissions );
    newPermissions.sort( comparePermissions );

    for( int i = 0; i < oldPermissions.size(); i++ ) {
        oldPermissions.get( i ).getActionsList().sort( compareActions );
        newPermissions.get( i ).getActionsList().sort( compareActions );
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < oldPermissions.size(); i++ ) {
        PersistablePermission p1 = oldPermissions.get( i );
        PersistablePermission p2 = newPermissions.get( i );

        if ( ! ( p1.getClass().getName().equals( p2.getClass().getName() ) ) &&
                ( p1.getTargetName().equals( p2.getTargetName() ) ) &&
                ( p1.getActionsList().equals( p2.getActionsList() ) ) ) {
            return true;
        }
     }

     return false;
```

Currently this is working but I am looking for assistance towards/advice on an optimized solution.

I am returning true if there is a change between the two, false otherwise.

Comment: The first paragraph made it totally unclear for me. There are two unsorted ArrayLists of objects. And then there are some other ArrayLists that each contain a single ArrayList each?

Comment: @Amongalen I updated my code to better show the lists. There are two unsorted ArrayLists, each of which contain objects plus another arraylist each, which is also unsorted.

Comment: All of your comparators seem to just be using natural ordering: you don't need to define these. Just use `sort()` with no argument.

Comment: Do you just want to check if those two outter ArrayLists are equal? That they have the same elements and the same goes for the inner ArrayLists? Or do you actually want to sort them? If it is the former there is no need to sort them, all you need to do is to flatten them and use `removeAll()` - if after that the size is 0 then they are equal. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155283/simple-way-to-compare-2-arraylists)

Comment: @Amongalen That does help, thank you!