# Validate dynamic (Span tag) Text using selenium Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I need help with writing a logic to validate a dynamic text, below tag is having text which would be changing constantly( to 6 unique words), i need to validate if those 6 unique words are same as expected text. is there a way to validate that.

Note - words are created in incremental way eg - a, ap, app, appl, apple

[Dynamic text Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnKFm.png)

Comment: Use //span[@class='search-placeholder'] by xpath then .getText(). I'm not sure how it's changing it's values.

Comment: @Prophet help me understand what do you mean

Comment: If you know the interval of change, you can simply collect texts after sleeps or waits into list of strings.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan, //span[@class='search-placeholder'] by xpath then .getText() will get text at that point of time, for example when page is loaded text will be app but that wont be complete word

Comment: @pburgr , i think I can get the interval time and any suggestion how i can get  all 6 unique word and validate with expected text

Comment: @MuthuAkilan what are you talking about?

Comment: @Prophet - thanks for letting me know .. will make sure to accept answer if it was helpful to me

Comment: @Prophet do read my previous comment and who are you to tell me what I should be doing ?

Comment: OK, no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static List<String> getDynamicText(WebDriver driver, By by, int intervalInMiliseconds, int iteration) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> collectedTexts = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= iteration; i++) {
        collectedTexts.add(driver.findElement(by).getText());
        Thread.sleep(intervalInMiliseconds);
    }
    return collectedTexts;
}
```

combine with [Compare two ArrayList of String for values inside it in Java Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66955564/compare-two-arraylist-of-string-for-values-inside-it-in-java-selenium/66965134#66965134)