# Shortest way to compare two arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

I am given two arraylists comprising of strings. I want to compare them and return a true if same and false otherwise.

What will be the shortest and ideal way to achieve this?

Edit: Order should be the same for both the lists.

Comment: posssible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589351/how-to-compare-two-arraylist

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Yes I am required to check the order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just

```
return list1.equals(list2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
 boolean isEqual= Arrays.deepEquals(list.toArray(), list2.toArray());
```

This will also return `true` for `Collection` like `List<String[]>` or `List<String[][]>` where `list.containsAll(list2)` will be failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to check if they contain exactly the same items (and you don't care about duplicates) then you could convert both to sets:

```
return new HashSet<T>(list).equals(new HashSet<T>(list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if every element of the first list are in the second list, you can simply use the `containsAll()` method.