# Two ArrayList compare and update one Arraylist or overwrite in android?

Tags: android, arraylist, compare

I have two Arraylist.

```
 ArrayList<Thumbnail> videoList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Giphy> giphyList = new ArrayList<>();
```

How to Compare two Arraylist and update `List<Giphy>` data in `ArrayList<Thumbnail>` or another third  Arraylist or overwrite in List data in `ArrayList<Thumbnail>`?

Here Two Class Thumbnail and Giphy. Giphy class is compare to Thumbnail. Giphy Class data stored in Arraylist and Arraylist data Update in ArrayList or data overwrite in ArrayList.

```
class Thumbnail{

  private String gif,videoUrl;
    private int id, thumbUp, thumbDown;

    public Thumbnail (int id,String gif,String videoUrl,int thumbUp,int thumbDown){


        this.gif = gif;
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    }

    public String getGif() {
        return gif;
    }

    public void setGif(String gif) {
        this.gif = gif;
    }

    public String getVideoUrl() {
        return videoUrl;
    }

    public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getThumbUp() {
        return thumbUp;
    }

    public int getThumbDown() {
        return thumbDown;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setThumbUp(int thumbUp) {
        this.thumbUp = thumbUp;
    }

    public void setThumbDown(int thumbDown) {
        this.thumbDown = thumbDown;
    }
}


}

@Entity
    Class Giphy{
        @Id
        private long id;
        private String url;
        private int thumbUp;
        private int thumbDown;


        public Giphy(){

        }

        public Giphy(long id,String url,int thumbUp,int thumbDown){

            this.id = id;
            this.url = url;
            this.thumbUp = thumbUp;
            this.thumbDown = thumbDown;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public int getThumbUp() {
            return thumbUp;
        }

        public int getThumbDown() {
            return thumbDown;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public void setThumbUp(int thumbUp) {
            this.thumbUp = thumbUp;
        }

        public void setThumbDown(int thumbDown) {
            this.thumbDown = thumbDown;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Kindly check the below link out in order to have an idea;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589351/how-to-compare-two-arraylist

Comment: What are the Giphy and Thumbnail classes? We can't know how to compare them if we don't know what they are.